# Error when allocating an object (linked list node) automatically, but not dynamically

Tags: c++, memory-management, linked-list

I was playing with automatic vs dynamic memory allocation for the linked list node. The following code represents the minimal working example.

The following code works and prints the result I expect:

```
list 1:
1 
list 2:
2 
list 3:
1 2
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
};

ListNode* merge_two_lists_iter(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {

    ListNode* res = nullptr;
    res = new ListNode(l1->val);
    res->next = new ListNode(l2->val);

    return res;
}

void print_list(ListNode* l) {
    while (l) {
        std::cout << l->val << " ";
        l = l->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    // List l1 consists of one node with value 1
    ListNode* l1 = new ListNode(1);

    // List l2 consists of one node with value 2
    ListNode* l2 = new ListNode(2);

    // List l3 is l1 and l2 merged
    ListNode* l3 = merge_two_lists_iter(l1, l2);

    std::cout << "list 1:" << std::endl;
    print_list(l1);
    std::cout << "list 2:" << std::endl;
    print_list(l2);
    std::cout << "list 3:" << std::endl;
    print_list(l3);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I replace the line `res = new ListNode(l1->val);` with the following:

```
ListNode test (l1->val);
res = &test;
```

The l3 seems to consist of some random values:

```
list 1:
1 
list 2:
2 
list 3:
-1845946528 -272632592 -2092384207 (lldb)
```

I tried to debug the `merge_two_lists_iter` function and the `l3` looks correct. However, the `print_list` function prints some random values. I would really appreciate if someone could ELI5 what is going on here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: The topic is discussed there in detail. It also answers the question what happens to local variables. Not a direct answer, I admit. I expect others to propose better duplicates.

Comment: I thought I return the memory of the local variable in both cases though, or am I wrong? Do you mean that when I use ```res = new ListNode(l1->val);```, I just get the correct answer by accident?

Comment: Got it now, ```test``` is a local variable you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListNode* merge_two_lists_iter(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {

    ListNode* res = nullptr;
    ListNode test (l1->val);
    res = &test;
    res->next = new ListNode(l2->val);

    return res;
}
```

I'm assuming that's what `merge_two_lists` looked like when you replaced that line.  Notice that `test` is a local variable that is allocated on the stack.  When the function returns `res`, `test` will go out of scope, so the function is returning an address of freed stack memory.  What actually happens to that memory after it's been freed isn't defined in the C-standard, though.  So in this case you got random garbage in the address of the merged list.

Comment: Oh, I see now, thank you. So, is this an example of the rule "use heap when you need the data in the variable after the function returns"?

Comment: Yes, that would be one reason that you would allocate memory on the heap.